# Java - casting to unknown type

Tags: java, list, casting

I'm creating a method that takes in a list containing an unknown type. The method returns the last element of the list. I will have different lists containing objects of different types being passed into this method. I need to somehow figure out the class type of the last element of the list passed in. I will then want to cast what I'm returning to it. I want this method to be very generic, I don't want to have to update it every time I want to pass in a list with a new class type. Any ideas?

```
public static Object getLastElement(List<? extends Object> cells) {
    return cells.get(cells.size() - 1);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `.getClass()` and `switch` on that - but there is no way to specify that in the return type and you've lost all type information by returning `Object` and having a `List<? extends Object>` to begin with. If you want a generic method use a generic parameter instead. `T getLastElement<T>(List<T> cells)`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Post an answer!

Comment: Are you doing something more complicated that simply returning the last element in the list . if not why not simply use the list method to return the last element directly without a method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to genericize your method to achieve this, as follows:

```
public static <T> T getLastElement(List<T> cells) {
  return cells.get(cells.size() - 1);
}
```

Here, you declare the method's return type as a generic type that is the same type as the elements in the list. Consequently, you don't even have to cast the result, as it already in the desired type.